# What is log-utility?

Tags: probability, statistics, utility

I came across this problem today:

> Calculate the log-utility optimal fraction of your capital to bet on a fair coin flip where you win $x$ on heads and lose $y$ on tails.

What is the meaning of log-utility in log-utility optimal fraction? Is this an portfolio management term or a statistics term? Apologies if this is in the wrong SE, please close this if it’s irrelevant!

Comment: Log utility on value $c$ is a function $u(c) = \log c$.  (It doesn't matter what base it is, since these are all equivalent up to a constant factor.)  It represents constant relative [risk aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion).  It's a term from economics.

Comment: @BrianTung How are they equivalent? For example, when throwing a coin, head gives \$2 and tail gives \$1. Then $\frac{\log2+\log1}{2}$ is obviously different from $\frac{\ln2+\ln1}{2}$

Comment: @CELLSecret: The log-utility is different, but all the utilities change by the same constant factor ($\ln 10$, in this case), and the optimal fraction is unchanged by this scaling factor.  That's what I mean.  Sorry that was unclear.

Comment: Oh I see. How do we determine if we would throw the coin again? If I have a question that states this: **You have 3 chances of throwing a dice. At the end of each throw, you can choose to keep the money or keep throwing. The money you are given is determined by the last throw's point value, that is, 1 for \$1 and 2 for \$2 etc. Assume you are risk averse and have log-utility, what is the expected amount of money?** Which base do I use here? (also I'm glad that you are still using StackExchange frequently, wasn't really expecting you to answer that quick lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the initial capital is $1$ unit of wealth and the fraction bet is $f$, then the capital after betting on the coin toss is

$$W_1 = 1 + f\xi$$

where $\xi$ is a binary random variable.  Assuming a fair coin and WLOG $x,y > 0$ enumerated in wealth units , we have  $$P(\xi = x) = P(\xi = -y) = 1/2$$

The expected capital is

$$E(W_1) = E(1 + f\xi) = 1+ f(x-y)/2$$

If $x >y$, you have an edge and the optimal fraction is $f^* = 1$ to maximize expected capital. However, if you are risk-averse you might not play to avoid a $50 \%$ chance of losing $y$.

A [utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility) function is a construct that assigns preferences to random  outcomes (gains and losses).  Specifically log utility was introduced by Bernoulli to resolve the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)

The optimal fraction with log utility is obtained by maximizing

$$E( \log W_1) = \frac{1}{2} \log(1 + fx) + \frac{1}{2} \log (1 - fy)$$

subject to the constraint $0 \leqslant f \leqslant 1$.